# git diff renamed/moved and modified files but skip renamed/moved and identical files

Tags: git, rename, move, git-diff, meld

I'm using:

```
git diff HEAD --diff-filter=R -M
```

with the meld external diff tool to show files that have been both renamed/moved and modified. I always do a git diff before doing a commit to both check my work and to properly assemble the commit message. Often times I'll rename/move files, which will also require some path changes within files that reference some renamed/moved files.

My problem is that in order to show the diff of a file that has been renamed and then modified, git diff also pops up a bunch of meld windows for files that have been renamed, but not modified. This can be very annoying. How to get git diff to skip the renamed but not modified files? I'm going to see all those files listed as being renamed/moved when I type git status in a much cleaner way, so I don't want the pop ups for identical files with git diff.

Answer (score 5):

I'm having the same problem and came up with an alias that did the trick (I'm using git 2.8.3)

```
[alias]
    difftoolr = "!git difftool \"$@\" -- .  $((git diff \"$1\" -M100% --diff-filter=R --name-only & git diff \"$1\" -M100% --diff-filter=R --name-only -R) | sed 's/\\(.*\\)/:(exclude)\\1/g') #"
```

**How to use:**

```
difftoolr commit1..commit2 -M
```

(see at the bottom for more examples)

**How it works:**

Imagine you have three files that have been renamed. One of them has its content actually changed (so you want to examine it using your difftool) but the other two are identical except for the path or name (and you want to ignore them).

```
(different) path/file.old  -> newPath/file.new
(identical) path/fileB.old -> newPath/fileB.new
(identical) path/fileC.old -> newPath/fileC.new
```

What the alias does is generating path specs that explicitly exclude `fileB` and `fileC`, i.e. those files that despite the renaming have the content unaltered.
In other words we are generating these filespecs:

```
-- . :(exclude)path/fileB.old :(exclude)newPath/fileB.new :(exclude)path/fileC.old :(exclude)newPath/fileC.new
```

Notice the (perhaps trickiest) part: the old file path and the new file path must be *both* explicitly excluded.

To do so, we issue a `git diff` with the following directives:

- `-M100%`: follow the renames. Which means that git is is assuming that some renaming was done, and will take this info into account to do pairwise comparisons. The threshold is 100%, which instructs git to consider renamed those files which have exactly the same content, but not the ones that were altered.
- `--diff-filter=R`: list only the files that git considers renamed, omit the others.
- `--names-only`: just output the file names, no other info
- `-R`: Reverse. In one piece of the script we swap the order of comparison (sort of switching left and right sides), so it will also output the old file names. For instance the `-R` directive lists the file `newPath/fileB.new` as `path/fileB.old`.
- `...sed...`: and finally we append the exclusion directive `:(exclude)` to the beginning of all filenames.

To deal with other cases I created three different aliases (not really elegant, I'd like something more flexible) so it can be used to specify the different kinds of comparison.

```
git difftoolr0 -M
git difftoolr1 HEAD~1..HEAD -M
git difftoolr2 HEAD --cached -M
```

In all cases the "sides of the comparisons" (commits, --cached or whatever) must be specified as the first parameter(s). For instance `git difftoolr2 -M HEAD --cached` won't work (because `-M` comes first).

```
[alias]
# takes no parameter: sample usage:  git difftoolr0  -M
difftoolr0 = "!git difftool \"$@\" -- .  $((git diff -M100% --diff-filter=R --name-only & git diff -M100% --diff-filter=R --name-only -R) | sed 's/\\(.*\\)/:(exclude)\\1/g') #"

# takes 1 parameter in first position: sample usage:  git difftoolr1 HEAD~1..HEAD -M
difftoolr1 = "!git difftool \"$@\" -- .  $((git diff \"$1\" -M100% --diff-filter=R --name-only & git diff \"$1\" -M100% --diff-filter=R --name-only -R) | sed 's/\\(.*\\)/:(exclude)\\1/g') #"

# takes 2 parameters in first positions: sample usage:  git difftoolr2 HEAD --cached  -M
difftoolr2 = "!git difftool \"$@\" -- .  $((git diff \"$1\" \"$2\" -M100% --diff-filter=R --name-only & git diff \"$1\" \"$2\" -M100% --diff-filter=R --name-only -R) | sed 's/\\(.*\\)/:(exclude)\\1/g') #"
```

Finally, BeyondCompare may suit your needs as well (and mine).
It easily allows to switch the side-by-side diff into an "unstructured" diff.

The latter strips off the folders and leaves just the names. If the filename is the same (but the paths may differ) they are considered two versions of the same file (for instance `path/file.png` and `newPath/file.png`). In this case, if the content has not changed, they can be omitted easily using a button on the upper bar.

In case "naming" conflicts occurs (several files on the same side of the comparison have the same name, under different paths), it would choose just one of them for the comparison, and ignore the others.

Comment: `git difftool "$@" -- .  $((git diff "$1" -M100% --diff-filter=R --name-only & git diff "$1" -M100% --diff-filter=R --name-only -R) | sed 's/\(.*\)/:(exclude)\1/g') #: 1: git difftool "$@" -- .  $((git diff "$1" -M100% --diff-filter=R --name-only & git diff "$1" -M100% --diff-filter=R --name-only -R) | sed 's/\(.*\)/:(exclude)\1/g') #: Syntax error: Missing '))'`

Comment: This is a slightly tangential comment -- I use "git difftool -d", which opens all the changed files in a single window (at least in meld) as a file listing, and then you can choose which file from the list to view by double clicking (command/control W closes the single file view and goes back to the file listing). This makes it so you don't have to wait for the window to open for every file.