# git diff historic version of (moved/renamed) file to current with external diff tool

Tags: git, diff

Is there a simple / good way to diff arbitrary old commit versions of a file with the current one regardless if it was moved / renamed - with an external diff tool.

I need a solution where I don't need to know if and when a file as moved or renamed (so I only know the new name / path) in the past.

So all I wand to supply to git oneliner / a script is:

- a path to the current file
- a historic commits sha
- what tool to use for the diff

All Variants I tried need the old path / name of the file to work... And here I found no way other than me to resolve and provide it.

I expect git can do what is needed to resolve the correct file paths with its Metadata-knowlede too. At least git diff -M seems to be patrial able to do it... but git difftool -M  --  fails to start the difftool with the new / current file and git difftool -M  --  doesn't start the difftool at all

Comment: Seems like a bug or rather not implemented feature. People do all kinds of workarounds: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44394214/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/44171487/7976758

Comment: What you want to do is not provided by Git. You do need one of the workarounds.

Comment: @j6t I fear you are right, I hope its a joke... in mercurial its a nobrainer... at least tortoisehg did it without a problem. Why is git considered better in first place? (No need to answer :-) )

Answer (score 1):

Here is another possible hack to find out what file should be inspected in the older commit:

```
$ git diff --name-status --follow <older> <recent> -- <path/to/file>
```

On my machine, I get an output stating:

```
R083   old/path/to/file   new/path/to/file
```

I don't know yet the inner details of `--follow` for `git diff`<sup>1</sup>, my blind guess would be it only looks at similarities between the two commits, you will have to test and check that part.

---

The possible outputs of `git diff --name-status` are:

```
[empty]   # <- no diff

[AMD...] path/to/file   # <- no file rename, regular known "Added/Modified/Deleted/..." tag

Rxyz old/path new/path  # <- rename was detected
```

with that in mind you can write a script which checks the output, and runs the appropriate diff command between 2 files.

---

For completeness: one way to get "the content of file `path/to/file` at commit `C`" is:

```
git show C:path/to/file
```

so, to compare file contents when the path changes, you can run:

```
# use your favorite diff tool here:
diff <(git show <old>:old/path/to/file) <(git show <recent>:new/path/to/file)
```

---

<sup>1</sup> `--follow` works with my git (version 2.43.0) but is an undocumented option of `git diff`, the doc is in the source code :)